# Текст не пропадает при обновлении страницы

Tags: php

Вот есть страничка логина, на ней есть вывод сообщнния о не правильном логине или пароле. Оно успешно выводится. Вот только при перезагрузке странички оно не исчезает. Помогите дураку)
и да, я знаю что код фиговый.

```html
<?php
session_start();
$login_stat = 'hide';
$users = 'admin';
$pass = '8546b20033603ae2f1aa61881b36befc';
 if($_POST['submit']){
 if($users == $_POST['user'] AND $pass == $_POST['pass'])
{
 $_SESSION['admin'] = $users;
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit;
 }
elseif ($_POST['user']!= '' AND $_POST['pass'] != '') {
    $login_stat = 'false';
}
}
if($_GET['do'] == 'logout'){
 unset($_SESSION['admin']);
 session_destroy();
}  
?> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\mousefollow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <title>Логин</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor2"></div>

<script>
    var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
    var cursor2 = document.querySelector(".cursor2");
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
        cursor.style.cssText = cursor2.style.cssText = "left: " + e.clientX + "px; top: " + e.clientY + "px;";
    });
</script>

<div class="login-box">
    <h1>Авторизация</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="textbox">
           <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
           <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Логин"> 
        </div>

        <div class="textbox">
            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
           <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Пароль">
        </div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Войти">
    </form>
   <div class="msg_box"> <?php
        if ($login_stat == 'false') {
            //function false () {
            echo '<p class="msg">Не правильный логин или пароль!</p>';
        }
          //  if ($_SESSION['message'] == 'false') {
            //    echo '<p class="msg"> ' . $_SESSION['message'] . ' </p>';
            //unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>
   </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ваша ошибка - `AND` и `&&` довольно-таки сильно разные вещи
2. Немного `улучшил` Ваш код.

```php
//Проверяем, что пользователь уже не залогинен т.к пользователь мог закрыть страницу
//потом снова открыть - не заставлять же его снова вводить логин и пароль, 
//но тут есть `дыра` в безопасности т.к это мог быть
//компьютер в общественном месте и пользователь не разлогинился, а просто
//закрыл страницу и следующий пользователь этого компьютера просто открыл
//этот же сайт - сессия еще не истекла и он сразу попал в админку
if ( count( $_SESSION ) > 0 && isset( $_SESSION['admin'] ) &&  $_SESSION['admin'] == $users ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
//Проверяем что через POST нам что-то передали
if ( count( $_POST ) > 0 ) {
   //Зачем проверять `$_POST['submit']` если мы сразу можем проверить 
   //что передали логин и пароль
   if ( isset( $_POST['user'] ) && isset( $_POST['pass'] ) ) {
       //И вот только тут проверяем, логин и пароль на совпадение
       if ( $_POST['user'] == $users && $_POST['pass'] == $pass ) {
          //Если правильно ввели логин и пароль - переходим в админку
          $_SESSION['admin'] = $users;
          header("Location: index.php");
          exit;
       }
       //Иначе был неверный ввод логина и пароля
       $authError = true; //флаг, что ошибка авторизации
   }
}
if( count( $_GET ) > 0 && isset( $GET['do'] ) && $_GET['do'] == 'logout' ) {
    unset($_SESSION['admin']);
    session_destroy();
}  

?>
```

Далее внутри Вашей страницы авторизации заменяете

```php
if ($login_stat == 'false') {
   ...
}
```

на

```php
if ( isset( $authError ) ) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, но это так и не решило основную проблему:
если ввести не правильные данные и перезагрузить страничку - надпись не пропадет.

Comment: Вы заменили `AND` на `&&` в условии `if($users == $_POST['user'] AND $pass == $_POST['pass'])` ?

Comment: Да, заменил. Если открыть новую страницу по той же ссылке все хорошо, но если обновить уже существующую - надпись не пропадет

Comment: Логично. Ведь Вы заново отправляете форму методом `POST`

Comment: Вы не поняли. Есили открыть страницу в новой вкладке и ничего не трогать - все окей
Но вот если после ввода не правильных данных обновить страничку и ничего не трогать - надпись останется
весь смысл был в том чтоб при перезагрузке она исчезала)

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы после вывода сообщения об ошибке это сообщение исчезало спустя N-ое кол-во секунд?

Comment: С помощью `jQuery` это делается примерно вот так `$(document).ready(function(){ if ( $('p.msg').length > 0 ) { setTimeout(5000, function(){ $('p.msg').fadeOut(); }); }  });`

Comment: Ладно, не забивайте себе голову. нужно чтоб надпись изчезала после перезагрузки страницы) просто оставьте это дело, пусть уже будет как есть

Comment: Перезагрузка страницы подразумевает повторную отправку формы `POST`-запросом. У Вас даже браузер будет предупреждать, что он повторно отправляет. А если без повторной отправки, то тогда не будет `POST`-данных и соотвественно не будет и сообщения об ошибке. Вы явно что-то путаете.